# Hold a key down in AutoIt

Tags: autoit

I'm running this [extremely simple] script:

```
#include<MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Send("{w down}")
Sleep(5000)
Send("{w up}")
```

What I want to do is press and hold the "w" key for 5 seconds; this script isn't working at all.

Comment: Do you really want do hold the key down for 5 sec (send only once) or do you wand to send w very often for 5 sec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different interpretations

```
Opt('SendKeyDelay', 50); Default speed
_Send('w', 5000)

Func _Send($text, $milliseconds)
    $time = TimerInit()
    Do
        Send($text)
    Until TimerDiff($time) > $milliseconds
EndFunc
```

Another way different result

```
#include <Misc.au3>

$timer=TimerInit()
Send("{w down}") ;Holds the w key down

While _IsPressed("57")
    Beep(1000, 100)       ; audiable proof
    If TimerDiff($timer) > 5000 Then ExitLoop
WEnd
Send("{w up}")    ;Releases the w key
```

and another one

```
#include <Date.au3>
HotKeySet("1", "_hold_w") ; 1

While 1
    Sleep(250)
WEnd

Func _hold_w()
    ConsoleWrite(_NowTime(5) & @CRLF)
    Opt('SendKeyDownDelay', 5000)
    Send('w')
    ConsoleWrite(_NowTime(5) & @CRLF)
EndFunc   ;==>_hold_w
```